# Difference between non-trivial and non-independent components in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

The terms "non-trivial" and "non-independent" are thrown around while referring to tensor components in general relativity. Especially with regard to the Christoffel symbols or the Riemann curvature tensor. What's the exact difference between them?

Comment: Please give us some context, such as a quote where someone applies these terms to something. I don't think these terms have any specific meaning in a general context.